# how add row of buttons dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, button

i am having a big problem with adding buttons_dynamically with java code
i want add buttons in my app so the number depends on the chars of **answer**
if the answer contains **4 chars** i should show 4 buttons , the below code is only to add one button i want to add more buttons  i need help

**main.java**

```
  TableRow tr= new TableRow(this);
        final Button btn = new Button(this);
       TableRow.LayoutParams tl= new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
               , TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
             btn.setText("h");
             tl.setMargins(10,10,0,0);
          btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           btn.setText(" ");
           }
         });


         tr.addView(btn,tl);

         setContentView(tr);
```

i

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way to do what you want is to add a view to your layout to act as a place holder for the buttons. I used a relative layout for this. My main layout has an edittext used for input, a button to trigger the generation of the new buttons, and a relative layout below that to hold the new buttons. The relative layout will not scroll by default so depending on what your end goal is some more work may be needed. Below is the onClick listener for the main button:

```
TableRow tr= new TableRow(MainActivity.this);

            for(char c:editText.getText().toString().toCharArray()) {
                final Button btn = new Button(MainActivity.this);
                TableRow.LayoutParams tl = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        , TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                btn.setText(String.valueOf(c));
                tl.setMargins(10, 10, 0, 0);
                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        btn.setText(" ");
                    }
                });


                tr.addView(btn, tl);
            }

            holder.removeAllViews();
            holder.addView(tr);
```

Comment: i want something different  i want something looks  like this http://prntscr.com/h2yo0b  it's my design but in this design the answer box has a fixed number of buttons i want to custmiz the number of buttons as the bumber of the logo chars plz help me am stuck in this over a week i've been searching  and anything and none helped me

Comment: You just need to change the logic so that every 5 characters if adds the view to the holder then makes a new table row. Also remove the `holder.removeAllViews()` or it will only ever show that last one.

Comment: i want to add them in the same table row or in the same line not every button in a in diffrent  row

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.slocamo.ucee.Test">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Eneter Text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/done"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/input"
        android:text="Done" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/done">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@color/black" />
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Following and use following code

```
parentLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
        input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
        findViewById(R.id.done).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String message = input.getText().toString().trim();
                int size = message.length();
                parentLayout.removeAllViews();
                if (size != 0) {
                    int loop = (message.length() / maxRowButtons) + 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < loop; i++) {
                        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(Test.this);
                        int buttonCount = size % maxRowButtons == 0 ? maxRowButtons : size % maxRowButtons;
                        for (int j = 0; j < buttonCount; j++) {
                            final Button btn = new Button(Test.this);
                            TableRow.LayoutParams tl = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                                    , TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                            btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                            btn.setText(" Hi ");
                            tl.setMargins(10, 10, 0, 0);
                            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    btn.setText(" ");
                                }
                            });
                            tableRow.addView(btn);
                        }
                        parentLayout.addView(tableRow);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope it will work for you